# Create a Json column from values in the same csv (My own json format) in python pandas

Tags: python, sql, json, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe-

```
+----------+----------+--------+
|     FNAME|     LNAME|     AGE| JSON FOR EACH CUSTOMER
+----------+----------+--------+
|      EARL|     JONES|      35|   ? 
|      MARK|      WOOD|      20|   ?
+----------+----------+--------+
```

And I have a json format -

```
{
  "applicantSegment": {
    "applicantName": {
      "name1": "" ,
      "name3": "" 
    },
    "ids": [
      {
        "type": "",
        "value": ""
      }
    ],
    "phones": [
      {
        "type": "",
        "value":""  
      }
    ],
    "emails": [
      {
        "value": "" 
      }
    ],
    "dob": {
      "dobDate": "" ,
      "age" : ""  
    }
  }
```

I need to create a new json column in the dataframe such that new column has json values for each row. For example the new column value for the first row would be  -

```
{
  "applicantSegment": {
    "applicantName": {
      "name1": "EARL" ,
      "name3": "JONES" 
    },
    "ids": [
      {
        "type": "",
        "value": ""
      }
    ],
    "phones": [
      {
        "type": "",
        "value":""  
      }
    ],
    "emails": [
      {
        "value": "" 
      }
    ],
    "dob": {
      "dobDate": "" ,
      "age": 35  
    }
  }
```

Can anyone help please? 
Required Dataframe with New json row

```
+----------+----------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------
|     FNAME|     LNAME|     AGE| JSON FOR EACH CUSTOMER
+----------+----------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------
|      EARL|     JONES|      35| {"applicantSegment": {"applicantName{"name1":
|          |                   |  "EARL","name3":"JONES" },"ids": [{"type": "","value": ""}],
|          |                   |  "phones"{"type":"","value":"" }],"emails": [{"value": "" }], 
|          |                   |   "dob": {"dobDate": "" ,"age":35  }}
|----------|----------|--------| ---------------------------------------------------------------                                                                             
|          |                   |  {Same as above but values from this row
|      MARK|      WOOD|      20|                                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack, but I answered you incorrectly before and felt bad, so I figured I'd give you something that at least works as you described until someone else comes along with a better answer.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame({'FNAME': ['EARL','MARK'],
                  'LNAME': ['JONES','WOOD'],
                  'AGE': ["35","20"]})

df['json_representation'] = """{ "applicantSegment": { "applicantName": { "name1": """ + df['FNAME'] + """, "name3": """ + df['LNAME'][i] + """  }, "ids": [ { "type": "", "value": "" } ], "phones": [ { "type": "", "value":""  } ], "emails": [ { "value": ""  } ], "dob": { "dobDate": "" , "age" : """ + df['AGE'][i] + """  } } })"""
```

I think the real solution is that you should build this with a python dictionary, but I don't see that you have any unique item that I could have used as a key.

```
d = {"applicantSegment": { "applicantName": { "name1": "" , "name3": ""  }, "ids": [ { "type": "", "value": "" } ], "phones": [ { "type": "", "value":""  } ], "emails": [ { "value": ""  } ], "dob": { "dobDate": "" , "age" : ""  } } }

s = ""
for i in df.index:
    d.update({ "applicantSegment": { "applicantName": { "name1": df['FNAME'][i] , "name3": df['LNAME'][i]  }, "ids": [ { "type": "", "value": "" } ], "phones": [ { "type": "", "value":""  } ], "emails": [ { "value": ""  } ], "dob": { "dobDate": "" , "age" : df['AGE'][i]  } } })
    s = s + ', ' + json.dumps(d)

s
```

Comment: Hi josh, is there a way to this without the for loop, I have around 5 lakh records?